# check if a certain revision (or tag) exists in SVN/subversion

Tags: svn, phing

I'm building a phing deployment script where I first ask the user to enter the revision/tag to deploy from svn.

when a user enters e.g. 0.1, I would like to check (with a linux script or from svn itself) IF this 0.1 revision actually exists. If it doesn't exist, I want to print an error and stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [SVN info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re13.html) command to get information about a folder, file, trunk, branch, tag.

Comment: thanks. I have something like: svn info http://server/repos/tags/xxx | grep 'Not a valid URL'

Can I check somehow that IF this returns something, I should catch "0" in a variable, otherwise 1?